# dialing a ussd code via URL on iPhone (iOS)

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, ussd

Is it possible to dial a USSD code via URL on iPhone using Safari or email (via hyperlink).

I am able to dial a normal phone number but it seems apple doesn't allow us to use * or # in the url? is it really like this?

This is what I am dialing via URL (hyperlink):

```
<a href="tel:*325#">Dial</a>
```

Comment: Yes, Apple disallows dialing with * or # using programming method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible without the use of private API in the objective c code (which apple won't accept on Apple store).

Please see the below mentioned URL:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

This is what they have mentioned: "Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number".

Hope it helps someone else.

Regards,

Reno Jones

Comment: That link is throwing 404

Answer (score -1):

Try to

```
replace:   #     to     %23
```

```html
this one:
<a href="tel:*325%23">Dial</a>

or this one:
<a href="tel://*325%23">Dial</a>
```

Comment: the # is still stripped